# converting functional component into class component react js

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to covert a functional component into a class component but I get error

functional component

```js
export default function App() {
  const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date())
  const changeDate = (e) => {
    setDateState(e)
  }
let clikededate = moment(dateState).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}
  return (
    <>
      <Calendar 
      value={dateState}
      onChange={changeDate}
      />
   <>
```

Class component

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
    
      dateState: new Date(),
    };

 changeDate(e) {
    this.setState({ dateState: e });
  }
 let clikededate = moment(this.state.dateState).format('MMMM Do YYYY')
render() {
 }

  return (
    <>
     <Calendar
       onChange={this.changeDate}
       value={this.dateState}
    />
   <>
  )
}
```

Comment: Share your Error, please.

Comment: Its quite hard to diagnose with the info we have at hand. What's the error though?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Comment: Try binding your `changeDate` method in the class constructor. I'm not sure how how the calendar component mange to change the synthetic event to the value you need but it's working that way on the functional component.

Comment: this.setState({ dateState: e }); i am getting here

Comment: Mmmm Are you extending your class with `React.Component`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5kb8?file=/src/App.js:423-464    from here i got the funtional componet

Comment: Please edit and format your class component code. It's kinda hard to know if it's an error caused by wrong class syntax

Comment: On the value prop of the calendar component you should use `value={this.state.dateState}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237864/discussion-between-meenu-ks-and-ktoxcon).

Comment: @Ktoxcon it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if its the only error but you have to add render() method wrapping the return in the class component.

Answer (score 0):

Return should be inside a render function. also any local variables should be inside the function it is being used. Try the following code;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
    
      dateState: new Date(),
    };

 changeDate(e) {
   
    this.setState({ dateState: e });
    // this.setState({ dateState: e.target.value }); // maybe this?
  
  }

render() {
  let clikededate = moment(this.state.dateState).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}

  return (
    <>
     <Calendar
       onChange={this.changeDate}
       value={this.dateState}
    />
   <>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think the return statement is already in the render method.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: you need to add more details of the error you're getting.

Comment: @Ktoxcon No. Render needs a return statement as well

Answer (score 0):

I see some issue

1- You close constructor after `changeDate` and `render` method, It's WORNG

2- e.target.value

3- bind `changeDate`

4- Close fragment

```
class **** extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 
  this.state = {
    dateState: new Date(),
  };
    this.changeDate= this.changeDate.bind(this);

}// close constructor

  changeDate(e) {
    this.setState({ dateState: e.target.value });// e.target.value 
  }

  let clikededate = moment(this.state.dateState).format('MMMM Do YYYY')
render() {
return (
  <>
   <Calendar
     onChange={this.changeDate}
     value={this.dateState}
  />
 </>//close your fragment
)
}
}
```